# set action bar as transparent android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, user-interface, android-actionbar

I've found a few people asked this question but none seemed to have a real answer..

Trying to set the action and status bar in android as transparent but ending up with this strange border between the action bar and the gradient background below despite both being the same colour apparently:

[image]

this is what I have so far:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    // set action bar colour
    val actionBar = supportActionBar

    // also tried this:
    // actionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

    actionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF")))
    actionBar?.title = ""

    // set status and nav bar to dark/ light
    backGroundColour()
    navBarColour()
}

private fun backGroundColour() {
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
    window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent)
    window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.gradient_background)
}
```

trying:

```
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION)
```

just moved the next view up, meaning that "next alarm" is to the left of the action bar's cogwheel etc, which I don't want.

main_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_foreground"
    android:title="Settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

themes:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.AlarmClockProject" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" >true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

set elevation(toolbar:elevation="0dp") to your layout file.Please refer below code snippet:

```
  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        toolbar:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: I need to add a namespace for toolbar it says for `toolbar:elevation="0dp"`

Comment: Here you can find the namespace for toolbar:elevation="0dp"
xmlns:toolbar="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: I actually found a way to change this programmatically.. its not the elevation here as far as I can see.. the pattern seems to be run once through he status and action bar and then again underneath

Comment: Okay...so can you please share your way of solving the problem?  so that I can know the other solution.

Comment: i mean i found a way to change the elevation programmatically, the real solution I dont have, for now I just matched the background colour of the status and action bars to the top of the gradient, it looks almost the same. but its only a cheat workaround.